# PHP if statement logic doesn't seem to be working when detecting if values are NULL

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

The premise of the if statement is to check a selection of fields from the database to check if they are empty(NULL). It is wise to mention at this point before getting to StackOverflow, I have tried with isset(), empty() and is_null() and still haven't managed to get this if statement to correctly identify fields that are empty. I'm not sure if I am missing something so simple here.

As explained before, I have tried isset(), empty() and is_null() and the if statement still seems to get stuck at the first iteration of the if statement thinking one or more of the fields are empty when in fact, they all contain a value.

Here is the if statement:

```
    if(($xQI['businessName'] == NULL) OR ($xQI['businessAddress1'] == NULL) OR ($xQI['businessCity'] == NULL) OR ($xQI['businessCounty'] == NULL) OR ($xQI['businessPostCode'] == NULL) OR ($xQI['businessTelephone'] == NULL) OR ($xQI['businessEmail'] == NULL) OR ($xQI['businessContactName'] == NULL)) {
      header('location:../quotes-electricity-view.php?id=' . $idmd5 . '&v=n&c=bi');
    } elseif(($xQI['electricity_mpanBottom'] == NULL) OR ($xQI['electricity_mpanTop'] == NULL)) {
      header('location:../quotes-electricity-view.php?id=' . $idmd5 . '&v=n&c=mpan');
    } elseif(($xQI['electricity_SiteName'] == NULL)) {
      header('location:../quotes-electricity-view.php?id=' . $idmd5 . '&v=n&c=sname');
    } elseif(($xQI['electricity_SiteUsage'] == NULL)) {
      header('location:../quotes-electricity-view.php?id=' . $idmd5 . '&v=n&c=eac');
    } else {
```

//code continues here to execute rest of page

Any and all help is appreciated at this point. The if statement only choses the top output as result, taking you to the page with &v=n&c=bi as the result, meaning it thinks one of the business detail entries is missing, when in fact in the test, every one of the fields has a value. many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us `var_dump($xQI)`?

Comment: Btw...use `||` instead of `OR`

Comment: @dharman thank you for providing the vital link to me answering my own question. I feel like a right dummie. The $xQI array was NULL. Reason being it was being closed before the if statement was running. So a simple moving of a bracket allowed the code to execute within the while loop allowing the values to be seen.

All because of a bracket... Also thanks to others who answered but the marked answer really should be thanks to dharman.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in part by @dharman.

@dharman thank you for providing the vital link to me answering my own question. I feel like a right dummie. The $xQI array was NULL. Reason being it was being closed before the if statement was running. So a simple moving of a bracket allowed the code to execute within the while loop allowing the values to be seen.

All because of a bracket... Also thanks to others who answered.

Comment: I fairness you are giving me credit, for something that you solved yourself. I only asked for additional details to your question. If you would like to answer your own question then you should present clear problem statement. If it was a typo then best to delete or just close the question.